# Wordpress custom field sorting, weird behavior: the latest post is at the end

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I am using Wordpress with Advanced Custom Fields. I have a custom post called "event" with a custom field "date" (I have added the field through ACF). The date field is formatted in the following way: "yyyy-mm-dd." Until now, sorting the custom posts worked fine using the following snippet:

```
$query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'tq_event_date',
    'meta_value' => date('Y-m-d'),
    'meta_compare' => '<',
    'orderby' => ['meta_key' => 'tq_event_date'],
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
]);

if($query->have_posts()) {
    $posts = $query->get_posts();
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        echo get_field('tq_event_date', $post->ID). ' ';
    }
}
```

Now I have added a new event post with date "2015-12-03." The sorting for some reason does not sort this post. Here are the results of this query:

```
2015-08-15
2015-07-15
2015-06-02
2015-05-18
2015-04-21
2015-04-18
2015-04-17
2015-04-02
2015-03-28
2014-11-25
2014-07-14
2014-07-04
2014-06-08
2014-05-31
2014-04-25
2014-04-26
2014-03-14
2014-03-15
2014-02-23
2014-02-23
2013-12-16
2013-11-19
2013-11-12
2013-07-24
2013-06-09
2013-05-12
2013-04-26
2013-04-19
2013-04-10
2013-04-05
2012-12-08
2012-11-02
2012-10-22
2012-10-09
2012-10-07
2012-06-23
2012-03-07
2012-02-12
2012-02-07
2011-06-18
2011-05-26
2011-04-30
2011-04-06
2011-02-26
2011-02-11
2011-01-28
2010-12-28
2010-11-22
2010-10-30
2010-10-16
2010-09-16
2010-05-29
2010-05-05
2010-03-29
2010-03-23
2015-12-03
```

For some reason, the last post is the one that I just added. I really cannot find the reason for this problem's existence... What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Changed the custom field from `date` to `tq_event_date` but still didn't work.

Comment: `date` is your custom field right? I pretty sure that `date` is already "taken" and is used as one of WP_Query's default fields. [(ref: WP_Query)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) Change your meta_key in database to somethink like `event_date` or even better: `{your or your company creds}_event_date` like `rs_event_date`. This way it never conflicts with default WP phrases.

Comment: I changed the event type but the result is still the same. For some reason, the newest post is not being sorted

Comment: **1.** Update your question with fixes **2.** Make sure all `meta_key`'s are updated and everything is correct in database **3.** Safest date format for code is `yyyymmdd` without any dots and dashes. You can format it to something beautiful before showing it in front-end

Comment: I checked all the meta keys and everything is fine in the database. I even wrote a query to sort all the posts based on the meta keys using SQL; and the result worked. However, wp_query doesn't work. This problem does not make any sense because for some reason the post that is created today is shown at the very end while all other posts with random orders shows it correctly...

Comment: @N00b The date format is correct, custom fields are sorted literally so it should not make a difference if all your dates are saved as `Ymd`, `Y-m-d` or `Y/m/d`. What does matter is that you cannot have a mix. so you cannot have some dates as `Ymd` and others as `Y-m-d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
'orderby' => ['meta_key' => 'tq_event_date']
```

didn't work. So, based on my context, where all the dates start with a number, I was able to sort the items in the following way:

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value'
```

If in the future something changes, I think the best way to solve the problem is doing it in PHP:

```
usort($posts, function($a, $b) {
    $d1 = get_field('tq_event_date', $a);
    $d2 = get_field('tq_event_date', $b);
    return strcmp($d2, $d1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you don't specify the type of meta_query which is alphabetical by default and might mess up numberic queries as stated in WP_Query codex.

Try this:

```
//Note how:

   //1. meta_query is also array 
   //2. I specify that meta_value is numeric and type is date

$event_args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'event',
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'meta_query'        => array(
                                       array(
                                           'key'            => 'tq_event_date',
                                           'meta_value_num' => date(Y-m-d),
                                           'type'           => 'DATE', //You can also try 'NUMERIC'
                                           'compare'        => '<',
                                       )
                                   ),
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
);

$events = new WP_Query( $event_args );

//etc
```

Comment: This didn't work but I found a solution.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Read my answer below.